# LWC Digital Experience Unauthorized Access

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I have a LWC page with 3 components and selecting a record from the third (right side) component, brings up a lightning-quick-action-panel.  This works great in normal lightning, but when I add the 3 components to a digital experience, all works but when I click on record in the side component, the panel displays but only showing the buttons, not the create record fields.
[image: normal salesforce lightning]

Below is the image I see in incognito window
[image: digital experience]

I opened Chrome Dev Tools and see this error

app:1 GET https://eia-lwc-developer-edition.na163.force.com/TimeTracker/webruntime/api/services/data/v52.0/ui-api/record-defaults/create/Time_Tracker__c?formFactor=Large&recordTypeId=012000000000000AAA 401 (Unauthorized)

the issue is: WHY CAN'T I SEE THE TIME_TRACKER__C FIELDS IN THE DIGITAL COMMUNITY?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might have used lightning data tags and you might not have access from profile or permission set level to view the object data.

Comment: the guest site user profile has access to read and create this object, so I think I have FLS correct.  And it works fine in normal lightning, just not in Digital Experience

Comment: Did you set up any required access to the record type(s), have you set all required API permissions and I wonder if the ui-api is functioning with sharing (which is now something that guest users are not compatible sith)...

Comment: I think you will need to [edit] your question to add detail of your guest user's permissions if you want real help here.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I figured out my issue; thanks to rene winkelmeyer's "How to build LWR sites with Experience Cloud", specifically episode 9; my missing item was: setup> all sites> select this site> Administration > Preferences > **Allow guest users to access public API**

when I did this, I saw my fields in an incognito chrome window. Because of a salesforce known issue:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GN1gQAG&title=community-guest-user-may-see-the-error-the-requested-resource-does-not-exist-while-creating-record-from-community-using-the-lightning-recordeditform

when I saved my window, I needed to use the isGuest boolean flag and then for normal salesforce jump over the window.open command

```js
   handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm '+ JSON.stringify(event.detail.fields));
        // next statement avoids  Error ‘The Requested resource does not exist’ in community
        if(isguest ==true)
        {
            window.open("/",'_top');
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here like me, this is also the fix for getting Flows to run via Guest Site User in LWR - thanks Mike!